# where-object failed to match hash table elements

Tags: powershell, filter, where-clause

I've got code below, I have a simple hashtable and wishes to filter out those `value=false` results:

```
PS D:\> $h=@{item1="$false";item2="$true"}
PS D:\> $h

Name                           Value
----                           -----
item1                          False
item2                          True

PS D:> $h|?{$_.Value -eq "$false"}
```

No output. Why? Is my syntax correct?

Answer (score 4):

You need an enumerator if you want to filter a hashtable like that:

```
$h.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Value -eq $false }
```

Also, if you want to filter out records where the value is `$false` you need to invert the condition:

```
$h.GetEnumerator() | ? { $_.Value -ne $false }
```

otherwise the filter would select items where the value is `$false`.